# Adding Extra JWT Claims via AWS API Gateway Lambda function when using Cognito

Tags: java, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Let's say we have the following scenario:

- AWS Cognito is used to handle the user pool and generate the JWT.
- AWS API Gateway with a few resource endpoints, requests are processed
  with lambda functions that use Cognito user pool to verify/autorize
  the incoming calls.

All endpoints need to have access to some extra user data/claims. These claims might change on every request, so I don't want to use any Cognito Pre XYZ Lambda Processors.

I also don't think it fits to use some sort of intercommunication between the lambdas to retrieve the needed user data/claims since this would need to occur on all endpoints and for every single request. Also reading the Database on each endpoint and request does not seem nice to me.

So, I'm thinking of adding a custom API Gateway lambda function as an entry point that retrieves the needed user data/claims. Then maybe decode the JWT and add the extra user data.

Doing it this way at the entry point, all other endpoints would have the needed 
JWT claims embedded, and they would then only need to read the wanted data from the JWT.

Wondering if this might be the way to go? Any tips or other solutions, guides to the correct path would be appreciated.

Thanks!